# Managing Windows Start menu & icons for WSL direct install software

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, windows-11

The WSL Dynamic Virtual Channel plugin (WSLDVCPlugin) seems to do an excellent job of creating Start menu links/searchability for Linux GUI applications which had been installed using a system package manager (for me it's apt in Ubuntu).

WSLDVCPlugin also creates a Windows icon from the application's original Linux one, and tacks the penguin in the icon's bottom-right corner so that it stands out as WSL on the taskbar.

I'd like to use that same Start menu & icon functionality for applications I'd installed without a package manager (specifically I want it for Anaconda navigator and Firefox developer edition). I have some ideas about how it might be done, but currently have insufficient Linux & WSL knowledge to make it happen.

Answer (score 5):

##### Short answer

For each app for which you want Windows to create a Start Menu entry, create an `<appname>.desktop` file.

##### Explanation

This looks (and seems to be, when I tried it) pretty straightforward.  According to the Github [readme](https://github.com/microsoft/wslg#wsl-dynamic-virtual-channel-plugin-wsldvcplugin) for WSLg:

> This channel is used by Weston to enumerate all Linux GUI applications (i.e. applications which have a desktop file entry of type gui) along with their launch command line and icon. The open source WSLDVCPlugin processes the list of Linux GUI applications sent over this channel and creates links for them in the Windows start menu.

So the Linux side of things is responsible for looking for `<appname>.desktop` files, like it usually does to create menu entries in the Linux desktop manager.  Microsoft has tapped this mechanism in their implementation to send notification of installed apps through RDP to Windows, where the plugin creates the Start Menu entry.

So to create a Windows Start Menu item, just create a corresponding `/usr/share/applications/.desktop':

```
sudo bash -c 'cat << EOF > /usr/share/applications/<appname>.desktop
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=<appname>
Exec=/path/to/app
EOF'
```

##### Additional notes

- The Start Menu item shows up within a second or so on my installation (Win 11 in a nested-virtualization Skylake VM).
- Note that it seems that the `.desktop` file does need to be in `/usr/share/applications`.  In my testing `~/.local/share/applications` did not work.
- Also, in my testing, desktop files with `Terminal=true` seem to be ignored.
- Deleting `<appname>.desktop` files does remove the Start Menu entry as well.

Comment: Side note, if you are using windows 11 and need to use a different x server for a specific application (e.g., clion is buggy in wslg) you'll need to point to a bash script that loads the app for you that sets the display environment variable up for you.